# Detect changing content of dynamic websites (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I want to build an Chrome extensions using a content script that extracts/highlights all links on a page, including Google search results links (but not limited to Google).

My problem is now, how can I detect that new content if available if the sites is highly dynamic. When I use the naive idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  alert('document ready'); 
});
```

then this event fires when I open Google. But actually performing query or going to the next results page do not trigger this event. Is there any website-agnostic (i.e., I don't have to know the id of DIVs, for example) event that fires when "the content has changed".

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener